# vscode shows error on dynamic imports when moduleResolution is NodeNext

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-module-resolution

In my project I use a library that uses package.json `exports`, so I have to use "NodeNext" module resolution for TypeScript. Everything is fine but dynamic imports for React.lazy.

```
const Home = React.lazy(() => import('home'));
                                        ^-------- vscode error here
```

> Cannot find module 'home' or its corresponding type declarations.

When I build/compile the project It looks like that the compiler does find the module but shows another error:

> TS2322: Type 'Promise<{ default: typeof import("...\src\home\index"); }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<{ default: ComponentType; }>'.
> Type '{ default: typeof import("...\src\home\index"); }' is not assignable to type '{ default: ComponentType; }'.
> Types of property 'default' are incompatible.
> Type 'typeof import("...\src\home\index")' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType'.

Note that I use `export default` in that component file. When I switch to "Node" module resolution this problem solves but those imports of that library which uses package.json `exports` don't resolve.